# get specific text from item showed in listview java

Tags: java, android, listview

As the code shows i'm getting JSON from PHP code and add it in a list of type Reservation User and then toast that list in a array Adapter.
but my problem is : i want to get those parameters again from the list view,
(date , time , tarif , stadiumN) when i click on a specific item(just those parameters and nothing else)
any ideas how ?
As shown  i typed

```
`myreservations.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaa: ",list1.get(i).toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

but it ouputs the toString with adding text.`

```
public class UserShowReservation extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView myreservations;
ArrayList<ReservationUser> list1 = new ArrayList<ReservationUser>();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
PreferenceUtils preferenceUtils;
int success=-1;
String id;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_show_reservation);
    myreservations = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lisreservationuser);
    preferenceUtils = new PreferenceUtils(getApplicationContext());
    id=preferenceUtils.getLastId();
    list1.clear();
    new NetworkRequestTask().execute();

    myreservations.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.e("aaaaaaaaaaaaa: ",list1.get(i).toString());

        }
    });
}

private class NetworkRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String connect = Utility.getReservationsUser+"userid="+id;
        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(connect, "POST", params1);
        try {
            success = json.getInt("success");
            if (success == 1) {
                JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("reservations");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    ReservationUser ru = new ReservationUser();
                    ru.date = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("date");
                    ru.time = arr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("time");
                    ru.finaltarif = arr.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("finaltarif");
                    ru.stadiunN=arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                    list1.add(ru);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(success==1) {
            ArrayAdapter<ReservationUser> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ReservationUser>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
            myreservations.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ReservationUser {
    public String date;
    public int time;
    public double finaltarif;
    public String stadiunN;
    public String toString() {
        return "DATE : " + date + "\nPrice : " + finaltarif + " $" + "\nTime : " + time + ":00" + "\nStadium : " + stadiunN;
    }

}
```

Comment: what are you getting right now? have tried to debug.

Comment: everything goes fine, but i need to get the values of an item for example , date : 2015-10-11  price : 20 $ ... so i just need 2015-10-11 and 20 without the others

Comment: @walid since you have implemented toString in a way and now when you are using list1.get(i).toString(); you are bound to get it in that way only...if you need values without tag text then either change implementation of toString or first take it in temp as String temp = list1.get(i).toString() and then manipulate it

Comment: `ReservationUser ru = list1.get(i)`  and use `String date = ru.date`

Comment: @kishorejethava thank you it worked :)